# AWK to look up Text

Tags: shell, awk, find

I want to be able to fetch people's whose number starts with 93 and were registered in 2021 from this file:

```
<ID>;<Name>;<Driving License ID>;<Contact>;<Bank ID>;<Balanca>;<Registration Date>
ID234580880;John;L1234567;961112223;234580880;150;2020-03-07
ID205202021;Elisa;L3453333;918564555;205202021;120;2021-04-06
ID223679890;Daniel;L1237774;938764333;223679890;100;2021-05-02
ID124563568;Peter;L6744567;938998994;124563568;50;2020-01-03
ID785645332;Mary;L9847366;964765322;785645332;90;2021-01-03
ID134563888;Sofia ;L3938889;916590890;134563888;30;2022-05-19
```

I have come up with this answer using awk:

```
awk '/;93/ && /2021-/' drivers.txt
```

But if by chance, anyone has a Bank ID that also starts with 93, as shown below, how could I get still get the data?

```
<ID>;<Name>;<Driving License ID>;<Contact>;<Bank ID>;<Balanca>;<Registration Date>
ID234580880;John;L1234567;961112223;234580880;150;2020-03-07
ID205202021;Elisa;L3453333;918564555;205202021;120;2021-04-06
ID223679890;Daniel;L1237774;938764333;223679890;100;2021-05-02
ID124563568;Peter;L6744567;938998994;124563568;50;2020-01-03
ID935645332;Mary;L9847366;964765322;935645332;90;2021-01-03
ID134563888;Sofia ;L3938889;916590890;134563888;30;2022-05-19
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do regex matching on specific fields:

```bash
awk -F';' '$4 ~ /^93/ && $7 ~ /^2021/'
```

Comment: and on another note, if I wanted to add a D before the L in the $3, in the same file, how could I achieve that? I thought of using this but it doesn't seem to work:
 awk -F';' '$3 ~ /^L/' drivers.txt | sed -i 's/L/DL/g' drivers.txt
Alternatively, I've come up with a working solution:

awk -F";" '{print $1 ";" $2 ";D" $3 ";" $4 ";" $5 ";" $6 ";" $7}' drivers.txt > temp.txt | mv temp.txt drivers.txt

Comment: GNU awk has an edit-in-place option: `gawk -i inplace 'BEGIN {FS = OFS = ";"} {$3 = "D" $3; print}' drivers.txt` or `gawk -i inplace 'BEGIN {FS = OFS = ";"} {sub(/^L/, "DL", $3); print}' drivers.txt`

Answer (score -1):

```
 echo "${input_data}" | 

 mawk '!-FS<NF' FS='^[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;93[0-9]+;.+;2021[-][0-9-]+$'
```

_

```
ID223679890;Daniel;L1237774;938764333;223679890;100;2021-05-02
```

to add the `"D"` to make it `"DL"`,

```
 gawk -e 'sub("^[^;]*;[^;]*;","&D") < NF' \
           FS='^[^;]*;[^;]*;[^;]*;93[0-9]+;.+;2021[-][0-9-]+$'
```

`ID223679890;Daniel;`***`DL`***`1237774;938764333;223679890;100;2021-05-02`